# How can I check if the inserted input matches with a variable in an .env file?

Tags: python, environment-variables

code:

```
import os
from os import environ

print("Welcome to [your company name here].")

s.sleep(1)

print("LOGIN PAGE")

s.sleep(0.5)

insertedUsername = input("Username: ")

if insertedUsername in os.environ:
  pass

else:
  print("Username does not exist!")
  exit()
```

I want to check if `insertedUsername` exists in a environment variable, but I don't know how. Help?

Comment: but according to your code, ```if insertedUsername in os.environ``` already checks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a value is in the environment table, you need to look specifically into its values. Otherwise, as you did, it will check for keys only.

```
if insertedUsername in environ.values():
    ....
```

Comment: @GlibberigeGozer if the answer solves your problem, consider accepting it.